# Why Select2 from Jquery shows me a disabled options when I paste in the search input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using `Select2 4.0.6-rc.0` from Jquery, the thing is that when I copy and paste a value to be searched and there is only one option, that option is disabled and I can select it nor click it.

In this image I'm expecting only one results cause `SF190` belongs to only one user. 
[image: See this image for better understanding]

But if the search brings more than one result everything is ok, like in this image:

[image]

This is the piece of code I'm using to initialize the Select2:

```
$('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
        width: '100%',
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        tags: [],
        ajax: {
            url: '<URL of my action>',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            delay: 1000,
            data: function (term) {
                return {
                    query: term.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                var res = data.map(function (item) {
                    return { id: item.Id, text: item.Id + ' ' + item.Name };
                });
                return {
                    results: res
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

I really don't know whats going on and I can't find any related solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/DarthVeyda/pen/wOJwvZ) based on your example (and [another codepen](https://codepen.io/leenawat/pen/RGwXaX/)):

```
$( ".select2" ).select2({        
  ajax: {
    url: "<url>",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 1000,
    //type: "POST", 
    tags: [],
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term // search term
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
                var res = data.map(function (item) {
                    return { id: item.id, text: item.text };
                });
                return {
                    results: res
                };
    },
  },
  minimumInputLength: 1
});
```

The only difference is that I removed the request type - I'm pretty sure that you are getting the data here, not posting it :) And if you try to put it back, the filter stops working, albeit in a different way (it returns the full list no matter what you put in the filter), so it might be the source of your problem here.

There is one more thing to consider - are you sure that there is no other code affecting your selectbox? Like something that applies to the `.js-data-example-ajax`, or any `<span>` with a single child (that's what a Select2 dropdown part is) etc.